# PHP form not submitting entries to email. I'm missing something

Tags: php, html

Updated: I have a simple PHP form that should submit data to an email address but it isn't sending it. it's just sending the field names.

Here's the code:

```
<?php 
$ToEmail = 'email@yahoo.com'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Site contact form'; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Surname: ".$_POST["surname"]."\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Designation: ".$_POST["designation"]."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Phone: ".nl2br($_POST["phone"])."\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".nl2br($_POST["email"])."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Opt in: ".nl2br($_POST["send"])."\r\n"; 
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 
?>


<form class="form-signin" name="index" action="index.php" method="post">

<img src="img/coffee.png" width="235" height="227">
<h2 class="form-signin-heading">Enter your information</h2>
    <input name="name" type="text" class="input-block-level" id="name"  placeholder="Name">
    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" name="surname"  id="surname" placeholder="Surname">
    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" name="designation" id="designation" placeholder="Designation">
    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Cell Number">
    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
    <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Send-me-helpful-information" name="send" checked>   <p>Send me helpful information</p>
   <input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" id="go" rel="leanModal" href="#thankyou">


    <p>Terms & Conditions Apply. 
<a href="terms.html">Click HERE</a></p>
  </form>
```

Please help

Comment: It's sending now but submits a blank email on page load. Does anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your submit button to this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Your PHP should look more like

```
if(!empty($_POST)) { // This is to say if the form is submitted.
    // All your PHP post stuff here. The email sending stuff.
    $errors = array();

    // Do this for all your required fields.
    if(isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != '') { // If there's a variable set and it isn't empty.
         $mailheader = "From: " . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n";
    } else {
         $errors[] = "No email submitted";
    }

    print_r($_POST); // This is for debugging. Remove it when satisfied.
    echo $MESSAGE_BODY; // Also for debugging. Ensure this is fine.

    if(empty($errors)) {
        if(mail()) { // Your mail function 
            // Successful mail send, either redirect or do whatever your do for successful send
        } else {
            // Mail failure, inform user the sending failed. Handle it as you wish. Errors will be sent out.
        }
    } else {
        print_r($errors); // See what's going error wise.
    }
}
```

Comment: I got this: Array ( [name] => Steve [surname] => Stifler [designation] => Driver [phone] => 0210000000 [email] => steve@stifler.com [send] => Send-me-helpful-information [submit] => submit ) Name: Steve Surname: Stifler Designation: Driver Phone: 0210000000 Email: steve@stifler.com

Comment: How does the echo $MESSAGE_BODY look? Does it contain the email body you're after. Post the revised code up to so we can see.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" action="" method="post"> // form like this
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"> // submit button like this 
</form>
<?php if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
$ToEmail = 'email@yahoo.com'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Site contact form'; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Surname: ".$_POST["surname"]."\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Designation: ".$_POST["designation"]."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Phone: ".$_POST["phone"]."\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 
} ?>
```

Comment: I replaced my php with yours

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

   //your sending email php code 
}
?>
```

Comment: buttons don't transmit their values in the form post

Comment: @DevZer0 they do, but only if they have `name` attribute.

Comment: @Zaffy you are right. php $_GET, $_POST and $_REQUEST only accept the name attribute.

Answer (score 1):

function `mail()`

uses **SMTP Server** so make sure it is perfectly configured and installed if you are using it on your local server such as WAMP or ZAMP.

rest if it still not working put your php code in between:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // ur php code here
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your form is posting some values, you need to have an `<input type="submit">` to post those. `name` is just an indentifier, if you will call it "submit", it won't work.

Try adding `<input type="submit" value="Whatever you want your text to be">` instead of `<button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary"><a id="go" rel="leanModal" href="#thankyou">Submit</a></button>`.

If you have another problem, please explain it more. What errors do you get? 
Try adding some `echo` to see where your program stops working.

Comment: Hi, I need the modal window to display after submission

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php    
if($_POST['submit']!="")
{
$ToEmail = 'email@yahoo.com'; 
$EmailSubject = 'Site contact form'; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Surname: ".$_POST["surname"]."\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Designation: ".$_POST["designation"]."\r\n";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Phone: ".$_POST["phone"]."\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure");
}
?>
```